# Error in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have written the following code in matlab, which should return the vector uexact:

```
function v=uexact(x,t)
  v=sin(2*pi*x)*exp(-4*pi^2*t);
end

function [ex]=test3

  h = 1/50; 
  T=1/2500; 

  x=0:h:1; 
  t=0:T:1; 



  ex=uexact(x,t);

end
```

I get the following warning message:

```
??? Error using ==> mtimes
Inner matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in ==> uexact at 3
  v=sin(2*pi*x)*exp(-4*pi^2*t);

Error in ==> test3 at 11
  ex=uexact(x,t);
```

Could you tell where my mistake is?

Comment: @IKavanagh I changed it, but I get again a warning message:

??? Error using ==> times
Matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in ==> uexact at 3
  v=sin(2.*pi.*x).*exp(-4.*pi.^2.*t);

Error in ==> test3 at 11
  ex=uexact(x,t);

Comment: Please describe what your function is supposed to return.

Comment: @Daniel It should return the vector uexact, which is the solution of a boundary/ initial value problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `t` and `x` are of different sizes. Then in your function you try to multiplicate `sin(2*pi*x)` wich is `1x51` with `exp(-4*pi^2*t)` which is `1x2501`. This is a dimension mismatch, as clearly stated in the error message you receive.

If you want to have a matrix as a solution `v=sin(2*pi*x)'*exp(-4*pi^2*t);` would do the trick.

Comment: Thank you very much!!! I am trying to calculate the order of accuracy of the finite difference backward euler method computiationally but I do not get the right result. Could I show you what I have tried?

Comment: Sure, although I'm a littlle rusty when it comes to ODE's. Just edit your question so that your follow up question is presented as well.

Comment: @DennisKlopfer I'm pretty sure that's not the best advice to give. I suspect that the *other* question has marginal connection to this one, so it might be wiser to add a new question altogether.